# Ansible variable for roles used several times

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a role with some variables than I using several times with different parameters like below:

```
  roles:
    - role: my_role
      vars:
        role_uuid: uuud_1
        first_param: first
    - role: my_role
      vars:
        role_uuid: uuid_2
        second_param: second
```

Problem is that when my role is executed:

- The first role instance, **uuid_1**, has a parameter *second_param* which is set to *second*
- The second role instance, **uuid_2**, has a parameter *first_param* that is set to *first*.

To resume, both instance have the parameters *first_param* and *second_param* set.

It seems that the parameters of the instances of the role *my_role* are merged then only the part that differ is really different (here *role_uuid*).

Is there are way to avoid this merge ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected with roles defined in the `roles` section.

Use [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) or [`import_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_role_module.html) module  in `tasks` (or `pre_tasks`) to avoid the problem:

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: my_role
    vars:
      role_uuid: uuud_1
      first_param: first
  - include_role:
      name: my_role
    vars:
      role_uuid: uuud_2
      second_param: second
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `include_role`/`import_role` are fairly new. Long time Ansible users might not know about them. I certainly didn't.

Comment: [`include_role` was introduced in November 2016](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/CHANGELOG.md#22-the-battle-of-evermore---11-01-2016)

Comment: As I said, fairly new. :)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware neither. The syntax (indentation) for the name is strange anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to dynamically include vars in *my_role*

```
tasks:
  - include_vars: "{{ role_id }}"
  - debug: msg="{{ role_id }}.first_param [ {{ first_param|default('undefined') }} ]"
  - debug: msg="{{ role_id }}.second_param [ {{ second_param|default('undefined') }} ]"
```

$ cat vars/id_1

```
first_param: 'first'
```

$ cat vars/id_2

```
second_param: 'second'
```

Then run the play

$ cat play.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: my_role
    vars:
      role_id: 'id_1'
  - include_role:
      name: my_role
    vars:
      role_id: 'id_2'
```

$ ansible-playbook play.yml | grep msg

```
"msg": "id_1.first_param [ first ]"
"msg": "id_1.second_param [ undefined ]"
"msg": "id_2.first_param [ undefined ]"
"msg": "id_2.second_param [ second ]"
```